# Can I specify a different length of stay during visa interview than the one mentioned in my DS-160

Tags: b1-b2-visas, us-visa

I am a chartered accountant working in India. I am 27 years old and single. I'm  going for group visa interview along with parents for b2 visa application. My brother is in USA on H1B and is sponsoring the trip for three of us.

In my application(DS-160), I have mentioned 3 months as the length of stay.
I've heard it helps if I specify a shorter time period as length of stay in interview with visa officer. If asked about length of stay in USA by visa officer during interview, should I specify a shorter duration (say 45 days)?

Comment: If you're going for 45 days, tell them 45 days. If your trip is planned for three months, say three months.

Answer (score 6):

You should mention the time period you intend to stay. Trying to make things up for the interview is not a good idea in general. This is especially important in case like that when you want to change the duration of stay. Remember, people conducting interviews have seen thousands of applicants, and are very good in finding out whether you're truthful. And if they decide you aren't truthful, you may end up being banned **permanently** from visiting the USA.

Regarding your question whether it helps to say you're vising for a shorter period: it depends. Please note that even 45 days is quite long for a usual tourist. Generally people with solid ties to their country (job, relatives to care about, social responsibilities, etc) find it difficult to leave for 45 days. So your case still won't fall into usual two-week-visitor category, and would attract more scrutiny and thus solid evidence of your ties to India.